# How would you deal with the situation of one Server - Many clients?

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server

I'm developing a classic server/client training project.

A Server has a ServerClient list of clients connected. I would to deal with the situation of closng the client connection from my ServerClient object then destroy itself...

I've developed a Server class that returns ServerClient object when a client connects. Then the ServerClient class has a member function called close() that needs to close the server client socket and destroy the ServerClient object.

```
class ServerClient {
private:
    Socket *socket;
    Server *server;
public:
    ServerClient::ServerClient (Socket *cs, Server *ss) : server(0), socket(0) {
        socket = cs;
        server = ss;
    }
    Socket *getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }
    void close() {
        server->closeClient(this);
    }
}

class Server {
private:
    std::vector<ServerClient*> clients;
public:
    ServerClient *acceptClient() {
        ... // accept client etc...
        ServerClient *sc = new ServerClient(this);
        clients.push_back(sc);
        return sc;
    }
    void closeClient(ServerClient *client) {
        // close the client socket
        client->getSocket()->close();
        ... // remove the client from the clients list
        // delete the client reference (I'll have care never using client object outside)
        delete client;
    }
}

// this way I can close the client connection and update server clients list
....
client->close();
```

That's the code I was thinking to develop... but I find this model quite odd.
Do you think there could be a better way to deal with the situation?

Thank you

Comment: The code looks fine to me.  Can you elaborate more why do you find the model is odd?

Comment: I don't like, for example, to have a public function closeClient which should be used by ServerClient... it appears an encapsulation violation to me.

Comment: You can change it to private and then give access to ServerClient class using friend.